# The difference between first byte and the address of element of first byte

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Consider the following 2 dimensional array:

```
array= {
       {'a','b','c'},
       {'d','e','f'},
       {'g','h','i'}
       }
```

The statement : `array`, would point to the address of the first byte of the array, and the statement: `&array[0][0]`, would point to the first byte of the first element of the array.

What is the difference between these two? Aren't they the same thing? How can we demonstrate the difference between these two using simple codes?

Comment: This is indeed the same address. But the effective type of each lvalue used to access it is different.

Comment: Do you understand how the _spot_ you're currently at is different from _you_? Same thing.

Comment: The code you show isn't C, or at least incorrect C. It does not compile.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the period in the second line of the matrix is just a typo, @alk

Comment: @DavidHoelzer: I did not even notice this :} ... -  I was referring to the missing type!

Comment: @alk, it's was a typo, i fixed it

Comment: @alk hah!  And I didn't even notice the missing type. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
   int arr[3][3] = {{'a','b','c'},
                    {'d','e','f'},
                    {'g','h','i'}
   };

   //value of the first elemnt
   printf("%c\n",arr[0][0]);

   //3 ways to print the address of the first element
   printf("%p\n",arr);
   printf("%p\n",(arr+0));
   printf("%p\n",&arr[0][0]);

   //the value of the first element in the second row
   printf("%c\n",arr[1][0]);
   //2 ways to use the address of the first element in the second row
   printf("%p\n",&arr[1][0]);
   printf("%p\n",(arr+1));
   return 0;
}
```

i hope this code will make it more clear, have a look at the comments.

Answer (score 3):

There are three things that represents the same address: `array` (which decays to `&array[0]`), `array[0]` (which decays to `&array[0][0]`) and `&array`.

While these three things results in the same address, they *represent* different things, and therefore have different types.

The expressions `array` and `&array[0]` have the type `char(*)[3]`.

The expressions `array[0]` and `&array[0][0]` have the type `char*`.

Finally the expression `&array` have the type `char(*)[3][3]`.

---

It might be easier to understand if it is shown a little more "graphically":

The array, in memory, looks something like this

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'd' | 'e' | 'f' | 'g' | 'h' | 'i' |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

If we put in where all the pointers are really pointing we have

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'd' | 'e' | 'f' | 'g' | 'h' | 'i' |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
^     ^           ^                 ^                 ^
|     |           |                 |                 |
|     |           &array[1]         &array[2]         &array[3]
|     |           |                 |                 |
|     |           &array[1][0]      &array[2][0]      &array[3][0]
|     |                                               |
|     &array[0][1]                                    |
|                                                     |
&array                                                (&array)[1]
|
&array[0]
|
&array[0][0]
```

Of course, `array[3]` is out of bounds, but it can be used while iterating over the array(s) using pointers to mark the end (i.e. you iterate while the pointer is less that e.g. `&array[3][0]`)

Comment: Why does `&array` look wrong to me?  It is early and I haven't had coffee yet, but I feel as though that should give me the location of the `array` pointer, not the head of the data.  The others look just fine, though.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude , is there an equivalent of the type() function of python in C

Comment: @BeshalJaenal No. C barely even have compile-time introspection .

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude , how do we find the type then?

Comment: @BeshalJaenal You don't. You have to figure it out yourself. :)

Comment: well, thanks anyway, (though I got 3 downvotes in this)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly there is error in your declaration you put dot(.) instead of comma(,).

In C  Arrays are stored continuously and "array" is the mnemonic here so the value of array and &array[0][0] is same.

Answer (score 0):

```
char array[3][3] = {
       {'a','b','c'},
       {'d','e','f'},
       {'g','h','i'}
       };

char *a = &array[0][0]; // compiles
char (*b)[3] = array; // compiles

char *c = array; // error
char (*d)[3] = &array[0][0]; // error
```

Comment: A bit of an explanation would be useful